# How does AFV select the winning videos?

Tags: americas-funniest-videos

How exactly does the *America's Funniest Videos* video competition work? I've always wondered, since I was a kid, why it seemed that the lamest videos were always selected as finalists. **How do they determine which videos are eligible and who decides the winners?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Through availability.

In an [interview](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/1531022/the-shocking-way-americas-funniest-home-videos-actually-picks-its-winners) with the former host of AFV, Tom Bergeron, it was revealed that they occasionally used old footage and picked the people who were available to be the finalists.

> "Sometimes videos had aired in previous seasons; other times, it was a factor of our taping date and who could make the trip."

Furthermore, the producers choose the finalists.

> 1. The voting procedure for the Contestant Shows will be as follows, unless otherwise specified:
>
> A. Of the videos included in each Contestant Show, the Producer will
>   select three (3) finalists based on humor and/or uniqueness as
>   determined by Producer in its sole discretion.  During the taping of
>   the show, members of the studio audience will vote for their favorite
>   video from among the three (3) finalists and use an electronic voting
>   system (or an alternate voting system, including but not limited to
>   voting by the general public in person, by telephone or over the
>   internet, as determined by Producer).  The first, second and third
>   prizes will be awarded based on the number of valid votes cast for
>   each of the three (3) finalists
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[AFV Contest Rules - AFV.com](https://afv.com/contest-rules/)</sub>

So, the producers trump almost everything in the choosing of the finalists.